# How to mimic form-data list with nested type that contains file in typescript?

Tags: typescript, postman, playwright, multipart, form-data

I got following form - I can easily "attach" the file for the root `fruit_image` property in typescript but not when it's a part of list `fruits[0]` of given type where the file is. How to accomplish that?
[image]

```
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
const fruitImage = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, './fruit-image.png'));

export const form = () => {
    return {
        id: 'some id',
        //below ok - got byte array
        fruit_image: {
            name: 'fruit-image.png',
            mimeType: 'png',
            buffer: fruitImage,
        },
        //below is not ok - posting this to endpoint results in null list
        fruits: [
            {
                id: 'banana',
                fruit_image: { name: 'fruit-image.png', mimeType: 'png', buffer: fruitImage }
            }
        ]
    };
};
```

Comment: That "form" that you "got" looks an awful lot like Postman... How about you show the actual HTML form you have or the real problem you're trying to solve? Also, knowing what the API expects is key to any debugging task involving APIs... Obviously if the API doesn't expect multiple fruits, sending multiple fruits is an exercise in futility.

Comment: @HereticMonkey It's REST endpoint - there is no HTML form. Above is real problem that requires to pass additional property along the file and the number of files is undetermined. It does work well in Postman (as per first screen) - just need to move it into proper object that is send as a `multipart` object. I don't need the code that works OK - it's just for showing what is working and what is not.

Comment: I mean I don't need to pass single `fruit_image` root property - need to pass list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
        //below is not ok - posting this to endpoint results in null list
        fruits: [
            {
                id: 'banana',
                fruit_image: { name: 'fruit-image.png', mimeType: 'png', buffer: fruitImage }
            }
        ]
```

This:

```
  'fruits[0].id': 'banana',
  'fruits[0].fruit_image': { name: 'fruit-image.png', mimeType: 'png', buffer: fruitImage }
```